# How does CUDA compiler know the divergence behaviour of warps?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

The **CUDA Programming Guide** (v4.1) describes this about **predicated instructions** in Sec 5.4.2:

> The compiler replaces a branch instruction with predicated
>   instructions only if the  number of instructions controlled by the
>   branch condition is less or equal to a  certain threshold: If the
>   compiler determines that the condition is likely to produce  many
>   divergent warps, this threshold is 7, otherwise it is 4.

1. How can a condition produce **many** divergent warps? A given condition can
   only split a warp into two pieces. What does *many* mean here?
2. Even if the above made sense, how can the compiler know about the runtime
   divergence behaviour of the warps?

Answer (score 2):

Warps are never "split". They either require "conditional execution" (so execution with non participating threads masked) to service conditionally divergent code paths, or they don't.

As for how a condition might product multiple divergent warps, consider the following contrived example:

```
if (threadIdx.x < 128) {
   // Only first four warps process here
   int modthirtytwo = threadIdx.x % 32;

   if (modthirtytwo == 0) {
      // Action A only first thread in the warp
   } else {
      // Action B for the other threads in the warp
   }
}
```

Here, the code can produce multiple divergent warps, and the compiler should be able to model the behaviour at compile time. Even better if launch bounds were specified to the compiler for the kernel. Compare this case with a shared memory reduction using only one warp.

```
if (threadIdx.x < 32) {
   if (threadIdx.x < 16)  shm[threadIdx.x] += shm[threadIdx.x+16];
   if (threadIdx.x < 8)   shm[threadIdx.x] += shm[threadIdx.x+8];
   if (threadIdx.x < 4)   shm[threadIdx.x] += shm[threadIdx.x+4];
   if (threadIdx.x < 2)   shm[threadIdx.x] += shm[threadIdx.x+2];
   if (threadIdx.x == 0)  shm[0] += shm[1];
}
```

Here the divergence is limited to a single warp per block. All that piece of text is saying is that the compiler behaviour in the two cases can be different.

It seems that "new" compiler (it has been used for OpenCL for a couple of years) has heurisitics for how many predicated instructions it should use before a branch becomes more economical. And it seems that a lot of branches in the instruction pipeline is not good for performance, so when the compiler can work out that code will produce a higher "branch density", it will prefer more predicated instructions instead of a branch.